# How to use model's default value in the serializer?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer defined by model's fields in the following way:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='abc')

class Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['f1']
```

Bit, running:

```
Serializer({}).data
```

Return an empty object. So how can I use the default value declared in the model? I know I can repeat the field in serializer, like that:

```
class Serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    f1 = serializers.CharField(default='abc')

Serializer({}).data
```

This will return the expected {'f1' : 'abc'}, but I do not want to repeat myself.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. Why would you want to use `.data` when you're passing a dict? Serializers either take an model instance and return a dict, or take a dict of data and create an object.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Yes I see it makes less sense, maybe I should rewrite the question. What I really want is to get the default field's value from the serializer, and send it to the client for example.

Comment: So why not `Serializer(MyModel()).data`?

Comment: Thanks, that's a progress :). I prefer to get it in a static way like, something like - MyModels.field.default, but that's simple enough and I can use this.